# How to write formula to display how many times one word is present in a row in ratio?

Tags: excel, formulas

I need to calculate a ratio of words presence. I have simple excel row with 7 values, and I have to answer the following question:

1. According to the info in your table, which value has the highest ratio? What is the ratio?

These are the values. I guess there might be 2 formulas, where in answer:

The [value which has the highest ratio - calc formula] has the highest ratio, and the ratio is [value from the formula which calculates the ratio] and it should be 3 out of 7.

Screenshot:
[image]

This is what I've come up with so far:

solution for first problem:
[image]

Comment: We can help with homework but you are expected to show some effort beyond copying the question from you assignment.

Comment: @Jeeped This ain't homework, and I spent the day trying different functions but I haven't figured out how to display the ratio, and I have the answer for the first one, sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: That question looks quite well written... does smell like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will calculate the ratio of whatever value is in "E8"

This will show the decimal ratio

```
=Countif(A:A,E8)/countif(A:A,"*") = 3/7
```

This will show the ratio

```
=Countif(A:A,E8)&"/"&countif(A:A,"*") = 3/7
```

Comment: Thank you. The second formula gives me a result of 3/0 instead of 3/7. Why this might be ?

Comment: In any cell (not on A) put the second part of the equation (=Countif(A:A,"*")) and see what that returns. The equation is asking to count any call that has a value i.e. not blank.

Comment: I tried putting that equation in another cell, still gives 0

Comment: Strange. Try =Countif(A:A,"<>"&"")

Comment: Is the first equation giving you the right decimal? 3/7 = .43? They should be the exact same thing except, we are just presenting in different in the other equation.

Comment: The previous equation gave me what I needed. Thanks for your help. It's not homework like some noobs told, I'm learning through things :)